# Python CMD Path issues

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Attempting to run python from CMD gives the following error:

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I thought setting the environment variable in advanced system settings to the following would resolve the issue.

```
;C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts
```

But I'm still getting the same error.

(I closed and re-opened CMD each time. Also did a system restart, did not resolve. running CMD as admin also didn't work)

I do have a: `C:\Python26` folder with some old scripts in it etc. Can't see how this would cause the issue. I tried deleting it but no luck.

As a last resort I made myself the owner of all files and removed read-only properties on all subfolders. No luck there either.

I tried the following combinations also btw:

```
C:\Python26
;C:\Python26
C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts
```

`echo %PATH%` gives the following

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;c:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;c:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Users\Timothy\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MicrosoftSQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Timothy\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Comment: What is the output of `echo %PATH%`?

Comment: Add C:\Python34 as last entry to your environment variables. This fixed my problem everytime i use python on windows.

Comment: @Adam Smith Hmm... `echo %PATH%` gives all paths except for python

Comment: do `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python\34` and echo it again. Sounds like you set your USER PATH, which doesn't play nice if there's a System level Env Var with the same name (for some stupid Windows-related reason)

Comment: @AdamSmith just so im not breaking anything... This will set my User Variable "PATH" (currently C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\npm) to ;C:\Python\34?   :::::edit:::::: I did as you advised and python DID show up in the echo....

Comment: @TGreenwood no the command I put up there will add `;C:\Python34` to your existing PATH until you close the cmd window

Comment: @AdamSmith It did show up in echo paths after i did as you advised. can i use this to permanently fix it? or will i have to use `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python\34` each time?

Comment: @AdamSmith I have edited the post as requested. I do appreciate the help :)

Comment: @TGreenwood okay now please copy the contents of your system Path and paste it above

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [this superuser question](http://superuser.com/questions/635082/too-many-folders-in-the-path-variable)

Comment: The official python3 installer can modify the PATH for you. Maybe the easiest way is to run this installer again and make sure to check the checkbox at the end of installer dialog. python(x,y) and can also set PATH for you.

Comment: @otterb Thanks! Found the fix though, see above. Think it was an issue with the version

Comment: Please post your solution as an *answer* rather than appendig it to your *question*...

Comment: The command to run myfile.py is simply `myfile.py` -- unless your installation is broken. Also, run `py -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` to verify the location of python.exe. This will give you the right directory to add to your system or user `PATH`. BTW, the deleted answer by Adam Smith about conflicting system and user PATH variables was wrong, at least for `PATH` and a couple other path-like variables. These get concatenated when a user is logged on or when the environment is reloaded.